# Saving Image to core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, uiimage

I am a newbie related to core data. Could any one help me to provide proper steps/ tutorial showing how to save images to core data and its retrival too.I am able to store string data already, but my app crashes when trying to save image.
For saving:

```
DataEvent *event = (DataEvent *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DataEvent"
                                                          inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SOME URL xxxxxxxxxxxx"];

NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url2];
imageSave=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageSave, 100.0);    
[event setValue:self.imageSave forKey:@"pictureData"];
```

For retrival:

```
 DataEvent *event = (DataEvent *)[eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[event valueForKey:@"pictureData"]];
 UIImageView *imageViewMainBackGround = [[UIImageView alloc] 
 CGRect rect3=CGRectMake(0,2,100.0,100.0); 
 imageViewMainBackGround.frame = rect3;
 [cell.contentView addSubview:imageViewMainBackGround];
 [imageViewMainBackGround release];
```

Comment: What is a datatype for "pictureData" in your model file?

Comment: "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store" where do you get this error?

Comment: instead of this line [event setValue:self.imageSave forKey:@"pictureData"]; try like this event.pictureData = imageData;

Comment: The second argument of UIImageJPEGRepresentation expects a number in the range 0 .. 1. You have used a number 100.0 which is out of range. You probably meant 1.0.

Answer (score 9):

To save:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myUIImage);

[newManagedObject setValue:imageData forKey:@"imageKey"];
```

And
To Retrive Image:

```
NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[selectedObject valueForKey:@"imageKey"]];
[[newCustomer yourImageView] setImage:image];
```

changed format

Answer (score 2):

> error: reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store"

**solution:**

delete the build project from simulator and clean from Product tab, now run the project.

Answer (score 1):

Don't change resolution if it's not necessary..

```
NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageSave, 0.0);
```

// and change following line

```
[event setValue:imageData forKey:@"pictureData"];
```

[See the store and Retrieve image from core data tutorial with sample code.](http://www.bukisa.com/articles/188059_iphone-core-data-tutorial-part-2)

Hope, this will help you..

Comment: Hi after doing this, i am getting error: reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";

Comment: where in saving or retrieving..?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the **pictureData** value of your managed object to the NSData object (in your case **imageData**), not the *imageSave* object, which is a *UIImage*.

Answer (score 0):

you can store images with this hacky way core data not supports images but you can convert images to strings.

```
self.selectedImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)?.base64EncodedString()
```

with this code you can convert images to strings.

for retrieving images you should get core data instance and reach image instance after reaching you should convert it back to image with this code

```
if let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: entity.img as! String, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) 
{let image = UIImage(data: decodedData)}
```

this is really simple way to storing images but if you have too much images in your app you should not store them in core data