# Capturing Signature to Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, uiimage

I have an app that creates a field for the user to sign their name. Upon clicking the save signature I want to create the image, save it as a png, and save it to core data.

"Pilot Signature" is it's own entity, with the property image.

```
- (IBAction)saveSignature:(id)sender)  {
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(mySignatureImage.image);

    // Create an image object for the new image.
    NSManagedObject *image =
    [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Image"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    self.mySignatureImage = imageData;
    // Set the image for the image managed object.
    [image setValue:image forKey:@"PilotSignatureImage"];
}
```

I get one error and one warning when I invoke `saveSignature`

> expected methody body

And on `self.MySignature.image` line I get

> incompatible types assigning to 'UIImageView" from "NSManagedObject"

I've looked similar posts on here about how to save image to core data, and I'm not having any luck figuring out what I did differently.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: See @Babul's answer at the bottom of this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311271/saving-image-to-core-data

Comment: Thanks for your reply, updating my code I get two errors with the line [newManagedObject setValue:imageData forKey:@"pilotSignatureImage" unknown received newmanagedobject and expected ]

Comment: Don't ask [duplicate questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968113/saving-signature-capture-to-core-data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code has serious problems. First, this line is not valid Objective-C:

```
- (IBAction)saveSignature:(id)sender)  {
```

That last `)` should not be there. This would probably explain an "expected method body" error, because you're confusing the compiler.

There's no `self.MySignature.image` line. I'm guessing that you mean the line that assigns a value to `self.mySignatureImage`.

```
self.mySignatureImage = imageData;
```

What that error is telling you is that `self.mySignatureImage` is a `UIImageView` but that `imageData` is an `NSManagedObject`. You can't assign one of those to the other, because they're completely unrelated things. Maybe you meant to type `self.mySignature.image` here instead, since you mentioned that in your question?

Finally this line doesn't make any sense:

```
[image setValue:image forKey:@"PilotSignatureImage"];
```

You're assigning `image` as an attribute of itself. That's got to be wrong. Maybe you want to be assigning `imageData` here?

I'm *guessing* that the last couple of lines should look like this, but it's impossible to be certain from the question:

```
self.mySignature.image = imageData;
[image setValue:imageData forKey:@"PilotSignatureImage"];
```

From this question and other related questions that you've asked, I think you would do well to review some of the basics of Objective-C. You seem to be having basic problems that aren't directly related to Core Data or image handling.